# How to delete desktop pictures in usr/share/backgrounds?

Tags: greeter

I installed xfdesktop and my login screen and background were changed to the green screen and the mouse :( 
I managed to change the background back to my selection, but the login screen has not changed. 
I looked for the solution on the forum, it said to add the selected picture into usr/share/backgrounds/
I found the folder but it does not let me delete pictures in there, it says I don't have the permission? How to get in there WITH permissions?
Thanks!
Fred

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fred,

Here is one method for changing the login screen for Elementary OS - Juno.

1. Save a picture of your choice in ~/Pictures
   For simplicity sake, my login picture will be called Login.jpg (restricting the filename of your picture to a single word followed by .jpg makes this easier, but that is **not** a necessity).
2. open Terminal via Applications -> Terminal (or Win+T)
3. Type: `cd /usr/share/backgrounds`
4. Type: `sudo rm elementaryos-default`
   **NOTE:** Enter your login password when prompted.
5. Type: `sudo cp ~/Pictures/Login.jpg Login.jpg`
6. Type: `sudo ln -s Login.jpg elementaryos-default`
7. Type: `ls -al` (check all folder privileges - everything should look identical)
8. Deleting a picture in this directory can be accomplished with `sudo rm pictureName.jpg` Where pictureName is replaced with the filename of what you want to delete.
9. ***Reboot***

   **Disclaimer:** Using `sudo` gives you carte blanche (read: total control) over your system.  Allow me to cite Ben Parker's words of wisdom:
   "With great power comes great responsibility."

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! In the end I used the sudo apt purge command to remove xfdesktop and it's all back to normal

Comment: Hi, I used these commands, but ended up with a black screen. I also downloaded lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings, it allowed me to set the picture, BUT now I have an ugly login screen instead of the smooth clean one by default. I tried sudo apt remove and purge lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings but still that login screen remains. Any idea?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I had some major commitments that demanded my full attention.  Anyway, if you perform steps 1-4 skip 5&6 and issue this command `sudo ln -s ./Ashim\ DSilva.jpg elementaryos-default` that would restore the original login screen after a reboot.

Comment: Thanks! As I did a clean reinstall, the problem has gone. I think I'll stay clear of too much tweaking, eOS works great and looks great just as it is.